# add data to DataGrid View through DataSet?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have a datagridview that is bound to a dataset

I defined the table and the columns, how I can programmaticlly insert data to it?

I did this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28VS.71%29.aspx

but it did not show the data in my DataGridView !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample example

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(quryString, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Emp");

//dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Emp"];
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("EmpID", "ID");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("FirstName", "FirstName");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("LastName", "LastName");
int row = ds.Tables["Emp"].Rows.Count - 1;

for (int r = 0; r<= row; r++)
{
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value = ds.Tables["Emp"].Rows[r].ItemArray[0];
dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables["Emp"].Rows[r].ItemArray[1];
dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables["Emp"].Rows[r].ItemArray[2];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

now you need to assign the values to the datagridview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// Add rows to dt 
datagridview.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: but datagridview is already configured with dataset!, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

it can be bounded directly by .

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

in C#

```
DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["your Table index which you want to bind with datagridview"];
```

**Like**

**`DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`**

In VB

```
DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables("your Table index which you want to bind with datagridview")
```

**like**

**`DataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)`**