# How can I assign metadata to a row in a DataSet/DataGridView pair?

Tags: .net, datagridview, dataset

When I open my form, I'm adding a bunch of rows to a DataSet that is bound to a DataGridView.  Later on, when I'm enumerating the rows in my DataGridView, I'd like to have access to some of the data that was used to populate the DataSet but is not stored in the DataSet proper.

Something like this:

```
public void OnStartup()
{
  foreach (var data in GetData())
  {
    var row = MyDataSet.MyTable.AddRow(data.Value);

    // here's the part where I'm not sure what to do.. ideally:
    row.GetDataGridViewRow().Tag = data.Metadata;
  }
}

public void LaterOn()
{
  foreach (var row in MyDataGridView.GetSelected())
  {
     var metadata = (Metadata)row.Tag;  // or something
     ...
  }
}
```

What is the best way to attach some metadata to a DataSet or DataGridView row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is one of those situations where there is no single 'right' way of doing it, just a matter of choosing an approach on a case by case basis.

There is nothing wrong with using the [`DataGridView` `Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.tag.aspx) property like this. Indeed, that is it's purpose, as stated on MSDN:

> The Tag property can store any object that you want to associate with
>   a band. This property is typically used to store identifying
>   information, such as a string name, a unique identifier (for example,
>   a Guid), or the index of the band's data in a database.

---

One alternative that I would consider is to use a `BindingList<T>` with custom backing objects as the `DataSource` rather than a `DataSet` and store the meta data in the backing objects. You can then access each object using the `DataGridViewRow`'s `DataBoundItem` property.

I would marginally favour this way since it keeps the data and the UI a little more separated and means you can grab the meta data even when you only have the backing object, but I doubt that there is any concrete difference in terms of performance or memory usage.

Comment: Since I already have a DataSet bound to the view I suppose I would prefer to stick with that.  Another problem, though, is that I'm not sure how technically to access the `Tag` with only a DataSet (ie. what does the `GetDataGridViewRow()` in my example actually do?).  Do I need to do a lookup on the DGV with the item I just added, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Ah sorry, managed to overlook that part of the question, thought you had already solved that. Yes, you would need to do such a lookup - that could end up being both slow and brittle so I'd suggest going more with the custom object route. What is the type you get back from GetData()?

Comment: It's just a custom POCO.  I agree that a lookup seems kludgey, so I'll give `BindingList<T>` a shot.

Comment: @ladenedge one other thought, thought again, this is getting ugly compared with using custom objects, is to copy your datatable to the grid like shown in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475830/add-data-to-datagrid-view-through-dataset

Comment: Ah, yep, if it is a custom POCO then I'd strongly recommend avoiding DataTables entirely - I've never found them to give anything compared to using BindingList<T> (if you need sorting you need to implement your own SortableBindingList but that isn't hard)

Comment: Not such a bad effort after all, and it feels much better with the `BindingList<T>` - thank you!